# How to use $event only for parent element in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have HTML code with `ng-click` event:

```
<div class="btn share" ng-click="do($event)">
   <span">1</span>
</div>
```

**Angular JS:**

```
$scope.do = function (event) {
  var target = angular.element(event.target);
  var parsed = parseInt(target.find('span').text(), 10);
}
```

When I click to element `div` or child element `span` is called event `do()`.
But if I click on span my counter inside `span` is not increment. Only by clicking parent element `div`.
How I can set same `$event` for `div` and `span` elements?

Comment: <span">1</span> is that " a typo or your error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to work with scope bindings instead of DOM textContent:

```
<div class="btn share" ng-click="do()">
   <span>{{count}}</span>
</div>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.count = 0;
$scope.do = function () {
    $scope.count++;
};
```

If you however still want to know why it failed with your approach, it's because you need to use `currentTarget`, not just `target`:

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.do = function(event) {
        var target = angular.element(event.currentTarget);
        var parsed = parseInt(target.find('span').text(), 10);
        target.find('span').text(parsed + 1);
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="btn share" ng-click="do($event)">
    <span>1</span>
</div>
```

> But don't do this, controller should not work with DOM at all, this is
>   not what controllers are for.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it the wrong way. Angular is not jQuery. You shouldn't do **any** DOM manipulation in the controller. The view should be generated based on the model, and not vice-versa.

The code should be

```
<div class="btn share" ng-click="do()">
    <span>{{ counter }}</span>
</div>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.counter = 1;
$scope.do = function() {
    doSomethingWithCounter($scope.counter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the same click event to your span also?

Like this

```
<span ng-click="do($event)"> 1 </span>
```